# How to use nginx to protect admin url transparently?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a WordPress service on my VPS and I find that there are requests to `/wp-login.php` from time to time. Though I have already setup a strong password, I don't want any random users to access admin panel easily. My WordPress is behind a nginx server and I hope that I can setup some nginx rule to harden the admin panel instead of using plugins. I believe this is not just a problem of WordPress but a problem for all public service with admin panel. So here is my question: is there any good solution to hide admin panel with nginx without touching the upstream service?

Answer (score 0):

I found a cookie-based solution to 'hide' admin panel to some extent by the following way:

1. Setup a secret URL, when user access the URL a secret cookie will be set in their browser and then redirect to the admin panel.
2. Verify the secret cookie whenever there are requests to the admin panel. Requests will be rejected if cookie is not matched.

Here is my nginx setup for WordPress

```
    set $admin_token "generate-your-own-token-with-uuidgen";
     
    # Setup a URL to inject admin_token cookie to brower.
    # You must change this URL to a secret one only you know.
    location = /secret-url-change-me {
        add_header Set-Cookie "admin_token=$admin_token; Path=/";
        return 302 "/wp-login.php";  # redirect to the admin panel
    }
    
    # Verify cookie for the URL you want to protect.
    location /wp-login.php {
        if ($cookie_admin_token != $admin_token) {
            return 403;
        }
        try_files $uri @wordpress;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @wordpress;
    }

    # upstream wordpress service
    location @wordpress{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6000;
    }
```

Now if a user access http://example.org/wp-login.php directly, they will get 403 error unless they access via http://example.org/secret-url-change-me .